# How do I find the average of a value in a dictionary, where a certain condition is met?

Tags: python, dictionary, average

It'd be interesting to know how this might be possible, I have gotten this info in a dictionary from a csv file.

Say for example we have the following dictionary, my actual dictionary I have is about 40 times the size, so I figured using an smaller example is easier to understand. For context purpose : My original dictionary is a big dictionary with about 10 different animals, where I need to find the average age, maximum price, etc. but only if the animal is a cat.

Hence I decided to give an alternative dictionary with the same principles but way smaller for questioning purposes.

```
example_dictionary = {'name': [Tim, Frank, Pete, Sam, Lauren, Darren, Michael], 'country': ['Netherlands', 'United Kingdom', 'United Kingdom', 'United Kingdom', 'United Kingdom', 'United Kingdom', 'Netherlands'], 'grade': [6.7, 7.6, 6.4, 6.8, 7.7, 8.6, 9.0]}
```

What I want to accomplish: Get the average, max and minimum grade of all the users, that are from the 'United Kingdom'

So I would eventually have the output of: "The average grade of users from the United Kingdom is: 7.42

I don't need the solution to all 3, I just need one example, then I can figure out the average min or max myself.

Comment: There are no stupid questions. Having said that, you haven't provided your attempts at solving that problem which is required here. This is a fairly basic problem so it's best for you to go with some python tutorial first, try solving that, and if you fail post your attempt here with explanation how it doesn't work.

Comment: Hey there Yevhen, thanks a bunch for your comment, The same issue applies though why I asked the question, I simply don't know what to type as a search query, I constantly find stackoverflow or other websites that just talk about the average of 1 specific value (for example with my example they just explain how to get the average grades of everyone rather than those from the UK) , Do you perhaps know an article, stackoverflow page, or a search query? That would be a massive help.

Comment: As I said, if you don't know the basics you need to start with [the basics](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/), not with your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

this is a fairly simple problem, and there are tons of ways to go about solving it really. As the commenter above mentioned, you should be able to figure this out with a little practice / python basics. But I'm sharing one solution to help you get started as you asked :)

```
sum_grades = 0
num_matches = 0
for country_, grade_ in zip(example_dictionary['country'], example_dictionary['grade']):
    if country_=='United Kingdom':
        sum_grades += grade_
        num_matches += 1

avg_uk_grades = sum_grades / num_matches

print(f"The average grade of users from the United Kingdom is: {avg_uk_grades}")
```

This should print out the average UK grades, as you asked for.

You can even achieve this with much shorter code using list-comprehensions. But I'll let you look into that if you're unfamiliar :)